# Solve error in multivariable equation

Tags: list-manipulation, differential-equations, equation-solving

I have the code that works for one variable equation.  However, when I modify it to include two coupled equations, solve gives me the error message which I do not understand. Below is the working code for single variable equation,

```
 ClearAll["Global`*"]
 ClearAll[equation, u, x, t];
 equation = x''[t] == x'[t] - x[t]
 terms = 3
 coef1 = Table[D[equation, {t, i}], {i, 1, terms}]
 coef2 = Prepend[coef1, equation]
 coef2 = Solve[coef2, {x''[t], x'''[t], x''''[t], x'''''[t]}][[1]] /. Rule :> Equal
```

and the output is,

$\left\{x''(t)=x'(t)-x(t),x^{(3)}(t)=-x(t),x^{(4)}(t)=-x'(t),x^{(5)}(t)=x(t)-x'(t)\right\}$

Modifying the above for two coupled equation the code is,

```
 ClearAll["Global`*"]
 ClearAll[equation, u, x, t];
 equation = {x''[t] == -x[t] + y[t], y''[t] == -y[t] + x[t]}
 terms = 3
 coef1 = Table[D[equation, {t, i}], {i, 1, terms}]
 coef2 = Prepend[coef1, equation]
 coef2 = Solve[coef2, {{x''[t], y''[t]}, {x'''[t], y'''[t]}, {x''''[t], 
  y''''[t]}, {x'''''[t], y'''''[t]}}][[1]] /. Rule :> Equal
```

and it gives me the following error message (from Solve),

```
 Solve:  {x''[t],y''[t]} is not a valid variable"
```

The objective is the same as before, to simplify each successive derivative and express it in terms of x[t], y[t], and x'[t], y'[t].

How do I fix the Solve issue - "the invalid variable definition"?

Comment: `Flatten` the lists of equations and variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not clear what you are trying to accomplish. You can solve the differential equations using [`DSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DSolve.html).

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

eqns = {x''[t] == -x[t] + y[t], y''[t] == -y[t] + x[t], x[0] == 1, 
   y[0] == 1, x'[0] == 2, y'[0] == 2};

sol = DSolve[eqns, {x, y}, t]

(* {{x -> Function[{t}, 1 + 2 t], y -> Function[{t}, 1 + 2 t]}} *)
```

Verifying the solutions,

```
And @@ (eqns /. sol[[1]])

(* True *)
```

Evaluating the functions and their derivatives

```
funcs = NestList[D[#, t] &, {x[t], y[t]}, 5]

(* {{x[t], y[t]}, {Derivative[1][x][t], Derivative[1][y][t]}, 
   {Derivative[2][x][t], Derivative[2][y][t]}, 
   {Derivative[3][x][t], Derivative[3][y][t]}, 
   {Derivative[4][x][t], Derivative[4][y][t]}, 
   {Derivative[5][x][t], Derivative[5][y][t]}} *)

funcs /. sol

(* {{{1 + 2 t, 1 + 2 t}, {2, 2}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}}} *)
```

**EDIT:**

```
equation = {x''[t] == -x[t] + y[t], y''[t] == -y[t] + x[t]};

Solve[NestList[D[#, t] &, equation, 3] // Flatten, 
   NestList[D[#, t] &, {x''[t], y''[t]}, 3] // Flatten][[1]] /.
 Rule :> Equal
```

[image]

Comment: @BobHanton, I am trying to avoid DSolve.  My task is to simplify listed derivatives and sort them like in single variable equation.

Comment: @BobHanton, thanks.  NestList function is new to me.  I understand it how it is used.  It is very elegant.